# How did a user with no actions and only 101 rep get the Mortarboard badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, badges

According to [this page](https://meta.superuser.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard), on Jul 19 '12 at 23:44 Tim Stone was awarded the Mortarboard badge which is defined as:

> Earn at least 200 reputation (the daily maximum) in a single day.

[image: Mortarboard awards page for SuperUser showing badge explanation and 5 users including Tim Stone with only 101 rep.]

How did he earn that badge when he has only 101 rep?  Is the Mortarboard badge system-wide, or did it have different (perhaps lower) criteria back in 2012?

Furthermore, although obviously known well elsewhere, he has [no actions on SU](https://superuser.com/users/147094/tim-stone)!  So I presume that the 101 is the Reputation Bonus (100) + the New User credit (1).  This makes this even more amusing!

Am I reading this right?  If it were a badge applied *across all SE* then I might understand, but those points don't match anything on his other sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tim Stone earned Mortarboard on meta.SU, not on SU. He earned it for several posts related to July 2012 election.

> Although reputation on meta is taken from the main site, the badge mechanics, including the badges based on reputation, still works, giving you badges based on reputation

(from [Should I really have been awarded mortarboard on a Per-site meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78603/should-i-really-have-been-awarded-mortarboard-on-a-per-site-meta)). That is, upvotes and downvotes on meta contribute to hidden meta-reputation, on the basis of which Mortarboard is awarded.

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't meta rep be included (or at least listed) on that page also?

Comment: meta has no rep. I got confused when I got the mortarboard here too, and I sort of kinda know how things work here!

Answer (score 1):

Meta sites still track reputation internally - it's just never displayed anywhere. For example, your "meta rep" right now is 23.

So you can still earn badges related to reputation, as odd as that may seem.

See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251249/mortarboard-continues-to-be-awarded-on-meta-stack-overflow